# WooCommerce Styling issues

Tags: php, css, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I really hope someone can help me with this, it is driving me mad. I have installed WooCommerce on an off-line test site on a default theme (TwentyThirteen) and it works and looks great.

When applying it to a theme I have developed however, the styling of the products completely break and display in a vertical list, with the links styled as per the rest of my page.

I've tried all the instructions on the WooCommerce website to integrate it to my theme (both methods of either using a catch all page, or adding hooks), and all of this still results in the same broken layout.

Now, through many hours of looking in to this and comparing my theme to that of TwentyThirteen, I have noticed that when I render the page, the '
ul and li tags of the products on TwentyThirteen theme are using woocommerce.css, and on mine just the styles I had already set.

So for some reason TwentyThirteen theme can look at the woocommerce stylesheet, and my theme can't. All the settings for WooCommerce are identical as I am just switching themes.

I have declared my style.css in my header but nothing else regarding enqueuing scripts etc. Is this where I am going wrong? And if that is the case could someone point me in the right direction on what to put either in my header or functions.php please to make it work? I seem have no trouble with any other plugin I use on my own theme.

Thanks for your time reading this and any advice you can give me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `body_class()` into your `<body>` tag like this :

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```